# Overriding methods of super class. Ambiguous reference compile time error

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, overriding

I've written a class to implement a double ended queue using a left justified array.
I also want to write a class to implement a double ended queue using a "circular" method.
I said that since it'll share some methods that i'll make it a subclass.
When I try to override the method insert first i get a compile time error.

```
CircularArrayBasedDeque.java:6: reference to insertFirst is ambiguous, both method insertFirst(EltType) in ArrayBasedDeque and method insertFirst(EltType) in CircularArrayBasedDeque match
            dq.insertFirst(i);
              ^
CircularArrayBasedDeque.java:21: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
    @Override
    ^
```

## ArrayBasedDeque.java

```
public class ArrayBasedDeque <EltType>
               implements Deque <EltType> 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        ArrayBasedDeque dq = new ArrayBasedDeque();
        for( int element = 0; element < 64; element ++) 
        {
            dq.insertFirst(element);
            System.out.println(dq);
        } 
        /**for( int element = 0; element < 25; element ++) 
           {
               dq.insertLast(element);
               System.out.println(dq);
           }
          */
        for( int element = dq.size(); element > 0; element --) 
        {
               dq.removeFirst();$
               System.out.println(dq);$
        }
    }
    private final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 2;
    private int capacity;
    private EltType elements[];
    private int first;
    private int last;
    public ArrayBasedDeque()
    {
        capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;
        elements = ( EltType[] ) ( new Object[INITIAL_CAPACITY] );
        first = -1;
        last = 0;
    }
    /**
      *  Returns the size of the Deque by
      *  returning the index of the first element + 1.
      *  @return the deque size.
      */
    public int size() 
    {
        return first + 1;
    }
    /**
      *  Returns true if and only if the deque is empty.
      *  @return true/false indication of emptiness.
      */
    public boolean isEmpty() 
    {
        return ( first + 1 == last );
    }
    /**
      *  Return the first element of the deque;
      *  illegal if the deque is empty.
      *  @return the front element.
      */
    public EltType first() 
    {
        if(isEmpty()) 
        {
            System.err.println("You cannot remove an element from an empty double sided queue");
        }
        return elements[first];
    }
    /**
      *  Return the last element of the deque;
      *  illegal if the deque is empty.
      *  @return the last element.
      */
    public EltType last() 
    {
        if(isEmpty()) 
        {
            System.err.println("You cannot remove an element from an empty double sided queue");
        }
        return elements[last];
    }
    /**
      *  Insert item at the front of the deque.
      *  @param element: the item to be added.
      */
    public void insertFirst( EltType element ) 
    {
        if(isFull()) 
        {
           expand();
        }
        elements[first + 1] = element;
        first++;
    }
    /**
      *  Insert item at the rear the deque.
      *  @param element: the item to be added.
      */
    public void insertLast( EltType element ) 
    {
        if(isFull()) 
        {
            expand();
        }
        for( int index = first + 1; index > 0; index-- ) 
        {
            elements[index] = elements[ index - 1 ];
        }
        elements[0] = element;
        first++;
    }
    /**
      *  Return and remove the front element of the deque;
      *  Illegal if deque is empty.
      */
    public EltType removeFirst() 
    {
        if(isEmpty()) 
        {
            System.err.println("You cannot remove an element from an empty double sided queue");
        }
        if(isQuarterFull())
        {
             contract();
        }
        return elements[first--];
    }
    /**
      *  Return and remove the last element of the deque;
      *  illegal if the deque is empty.
      */
    public EltType removeLast() 
    {
        if(isEmpty()) 
        {
            System.err.println("You cannot remove an element from an empty double sided queue");
        }
        if(isQuarterFull())
        {
             contract();
        }
        EltType last = elements[0];
        for (int index = 0; index < first; index ++) 
        {
             elements[index] = elements[ index + 1 ];
        }

        return last;
    }
    /**
      *  Return true if and only if the queue is full.
      *  @return boolean representsion of weather the queue is full.
      */
    public boolean isFull() 
    {
        return ( size() == capacity );
    }
    /**
      *  Return true if and only if the queue is quarter full
      *  @return boolean representation of weather the queue is quarter full.
      */
    public boolean isQuarterFull() 
    {
        return ( size() == capacity / 4 );
    }
    /**
      *  Doubles the capacity of the array representing the queue
      */
    public void expand() 
    {
        EltType[] tmp;
        tmp = ( EltType[] ) ( new Object[this.size() * 2] );
        for( int element = 0; element < capacity ; element++ ) 
        {
            tmp[element] = elements[element];
        }
        capacity *= 2;
        elements = tmp;
    }
    /**
      *  Halves the capacity of the array representing the queue
      */
    public void contract() 
    {
        EltType[] tmp;
        tmp = ( EltType[] ) ( new Object[ capacity / 2 ] );
        for ( int element = 0; element < size(); element++ ) 
        {
            tmp[element] = elements[element];
        }
        capacity /= 4;
        elements = tmp;
    }
    /**
      *  Returns a string representation of the deque.
      *  @return a string representation of the deque.
      */
    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        String string = "{ ";
        for (int index = 0; index <= first; index ++) 
        {
            string = string + elements[index] + " ";
        }
        string = string + "}";
        string = string + "\n";
        string = string + "Size " + size();
        string = string + "\n";
        string = string + "Capacity " + capacity;
        string = string + "\n";
        return string;
    }
}
```

## CircularArrayBasedDeque.java

```
public class CircularArrayBasedDeque <EltType>
                            extends ArrayBasedDeque
{
    public static void main( String[] args ) 
    {
        CircularArrayBasedDeque dq = new CircularArrayBasedDeque();
        for ( int i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
        {
            dq.insertFirst(i);
            System.out.println(dq);
        }
    }
    private final int INITIAL_CAPACITY = 20;
    private int capacity;
    private int first;
    private int last;
    private EltType[] elements; 
    public CircularArrayBasedDeque() 
    {
        capacity = INITIAL_CAPACITY;
        elements = ( EltType[] ) ( new Object[INITIAL_CAPACITY] );
        first = 0;
        last = 0;
    }
    @Override
    public void insertFirst( EltType element ) 
    {
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isEmpty() 
    {
        return ( first == last );
    }
    @Override
    public int size() 
    {
        return ( capacity - first + last );
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help in advance.
I'm new to OOP and find class design and inheritance confusing.

Comment: I not sure having `$` at the end of each line improve clarity. I am more used to read code without end of line markers. ;)

Comment: Sorry.In future I'll turn it off in vim before copying:)Also thank you for editing my post:)Sorry it was such a mess:P It was my first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is that you dropped the generics from your CircularArrayBasedDeque class, instead use:

```
public class CircularArrayBasedDeque<EltType> extends ArrayBasedDeque<EltType>
```

the way you have it currently defined, the `EltType` in your CircularArrayBasedDeque class is *different* from the `EltType` in your ArrayBasedDeque class which is why the override is not working correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response jtahlborn :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you pass the `EltType` parameter when you extend the base class:

```
public class CircularArrayBasedDeque <EltType>
extends ArrayBasedDeque <EltType> {
//                      ^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response John :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following to get rid of the compile time error:

Replace

```
public class CircularArrayBasedDeque<EltType> extends ArrayBasedDeque
```

with

```
public class CircularArrayBasedDeque<EltType> extends ArrayBasedDeque<EltType>
```